# AttributeError: type object 'MyModel' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I have created view MyView (CreateView) and the model and the form and get an error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'MyModel' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Here is my view:

```
class MyView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = "myapp/template1.html"
```

Here is my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    free_day = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('MyModel')
        verbose_name_plural = _('MyModels')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.free_day
```

My form:

```
class MyInputForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('user', 'free_day', )
```

Here is my traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /freedays/addvacation/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mariusz/.virtualenvs/urlop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mariusz/.virtualenvs/urlop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 394, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mariusz/.virtualenvs/urlop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mariusz/.virtualenvs/urlop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 87, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mariusz/.virtualenvs/urlop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 203, in get
    return super(BaseCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mariusz/.virtualenvs/urlop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 161, in get
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
  File "/home/mariusz/.virtualenvs/urlop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 119, in get_form_class
    return model_forms.modelform_factory(model, fields=self.fields)
  File "/home/mariusz/.virtualenvs/urlop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 539, in modelform_factory
    return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
  File "/home/mariusz/.virtualenvs/urlop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 284, in __new__
    opts.help_texts, opts.error_messages)
  File "/home/mariusz/.virtualenvs/urlop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 184, in fields_for_model
    opts = model._meta
AttributeError: type object 'MyModel' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback.

Comment: I added full traceback.

Comment: tried out exactly your code and it works for me. what's in your `urls.py` pointing to this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see exactly why it's giving that error (it seems that MyModel is not actually your model class - have you redefined it elsewhere?), but there is one obvious problem: your view should be referencing the form you have defined, not the model directly.

```
class MyView(CreateView):
    form_class = MyInputForm
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following:

```
def get(request,self):
```

You could use something like this:

```
def get(self,request):
```

Everything else should be just fine!!!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried having meta as a function, to look like this;

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    free_day = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def Meta():
        verbose_name = _('MyModel')
        verbose_name_plural = _('MyModels')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.free_day
```